# How to add non-variable text into javascript print popup?

Tags: javascript, printing, popup

I have a recipe blog and there is an option to print just the recipe from a blog post, this is all set up and works great, the right stuff gets printed etc using this javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

// Print recipe using iframe
function printRecipe(){
var content = document.getElementById(&quot;recipe&quot;);
var pri = document.getElementById(&quot;ifmcontentstoprint&quot;).contentWindow;
pri.document.open();
pri.document.write(content.innerHTML);
pri.document.close();
pri.focus();
pri.print();
}
```

What I want to do is to add a footer with the website address to the bottom of every 'Print Recipe'. This will be unchanging from recipe to recipe, but I don't want it showing on the original recipe so it needs to show up only when the recipe is printed. So i know i have to add it somewhere in this code, but so far have had no luck.

I have tried to search loads of forums with no real answer to what must be a simply question..

please help! 
Thanks.

Comment: +1 to cancel the -1, not sure why this question was downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line:

```
pri.document.write(content.innerHTML);
```

Add your footer:

```
pri.document.write("My custom footer! Can include HTML");
```

Final code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

// Print recipe using iframe
function printRecipe(){
var content = document.getElementById("recipe");
var pri = document.getElementById("ifmcontentstoprint").contentWindow;
pri.document.open();
pri.document.write(content.innerHTML);
pri.document.write("My custom footer! Can include HTML");
pri.document.close();
pri.focus();
pri.print();
}
</script>
```

Comment: +1. Note (for OP) that "Can include HTML" also means appropriate styles can be applied.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've asked so many people and no one has given me the answer until now!! It works! :-)

Comment: well at least now you know where to come for help! :)